# why do quotes matter in git grep -- pathspec?

Tags: git

With files:

```
.\contains-x.txt
.\subdir\also-contains-x.txt
```

I get different results if I  quote the pathspec:

```
$ git grep x -- *.txt
contains-x.txt:x

$ git grep x -- '*.txt'
contains-x.txt:x
subdir\also-contains-x.txt:x
```

why the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Without quotes, your `patspec` is expanded by the shell before `git` gets it. It is similar case with `echo` example below.

```
$ touch contains-x.txt
$ ls
contains-x.txt
$ echo *.txt
contains-x.txt
$ echo '*.txt'
*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the quotes, the shell expands the `*` so instead of passing `*.txt` to `git grep`, you'd be passing a list of files in the current directory that match this pattern.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple.

When you add "" to git command it simply execute it on all the project including subfolders,
for example

```
git add *.txt   -> will add all the *.txt files in the current directory
git add '*.txt' -> will add all the .txt file in any directory (recursive)
```

Comment: You've just restated the question, you have NOT explained **why**. There were already two answers that explained it was because without quotes the shell expands the glob to the files in the current directory before passing it to git.